# Sign for triple product of second derivatives

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Denote its Hessian by $\nabla^2 u = (\partial_{ij}u)$. I've encountered the real-valued expression
$$- \sum_{i,j,l=1}^d\partial_{il}u\partial_{ij}u \partial_{lj}u, \tag{1}$$
and I am curious whether this quantity has a sign in general, in particular whether it's nonpositive.

If $\nabla^2 u$ is positive definite, then
$$(1) = -\sum_{l=1}^d \langle{\nabla\partial_{l}u, (\nabla^2 u)\nabla\partial_{l}u}\rangle \le 0,$$
since each summand is $\le 0$. But for my purposes, I don't want to assume $\nabla^2 u$ is positive definite.

Comment: Where have you encountered it, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Jollywatt An estimate for a parabolic equation.

Comment: even when $d=1$, $-(\partial^2_x u)^3$ can change sign if $\partial^2_x u$ changes sign

Comment: @fwd Silly me, you are, of course, correct. In my head, I was thinking $\partial_x^2 u\ge 0$, which is equivalent to saying that the Hessian is positive definite. Unfortunately, I don't think for my purposes I know that the Hessian is positive definite (i.e. $u$ is convex).